# Error with using BERT model from Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, bert-language-model

I have tried to follow Tensorflow instructions to use BERT model: (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/classify_text_with_bert)

However, when I run these lines:

```
text_test = ['this is such an amazing movie!']
text_preprocessed = bert_preprocess_model(text_test)
```

I got the below error:

```
InvalidArgumentError:  Trying to access resource using the wrong type. Expected class tensorflow::lookup::LookupInterface got class tensorflow::lookup::LookupInterface
     [[{{node StatefulPartitionedCall/StatefulPartitionedCall/bert_tokenizer/StatefulPartitionedCall/WordpieceTokenizeWithOffsets/WordpieceTokenizeWithOffsets/WordpieceTokenizeWithOffsets}}]] [Op:__inference_restored_function_body_72474]
```

The two classes are exactly the same: "tensorflow::lookup::LookupInterface". Could anyone help with this? Thank you.

Comment: I have the same issue on windows10 any solution?

Comment: i report it right now https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/46096

Comment: Same issue here! Did you guys find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I found this bug report on GitHub: https://github.com/tensorflow/text/issues/476

It appears that they've acknowledged it as a bug and are trying to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I also got same error in windows 10.
Then I tried it in wsl2 ubuntu 18.04 and works fine.
How about try it in wsl2 ubuntu